# How do I execute a javascript function from an HTML element and send that elements name without use its name specifically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If there is an answer to this question out there I can not find it.

I have the following function in `JavaScript` and need to be able to reuse it over and over.

```js
function ParentService_load(_Object) {
    $(_Object.parent.parent).jqxDropDownButton({
        ...
    });
    $(_Object).jqxGrid({
        ...
    });
    $(_Object).bind('rowselect', function(event) {
        ...
        var row = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
        ...
        $(_Object.parent.parent).jqxDropDownButton('setContent', dropDownContent);
        if (row["servicename"].toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
            $(_Object.parent.parent).jqxDropDownButton('close');
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="jqxParentServiceDropdownButton">
    <div id='jqxParentServiceDropdownWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxParentServiceDropdownGrid" onload="ParentService_load(this);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't found a definitive way to call a javascript or jquery function from an element and have that function use that elements' name, etc... So how would I accomplish this?

Comment: are you sure you need to run it over and over like this?
have you considered using jquery .each() ? - to bind to all elements  that have a class, or tagname?

Answer (score 1):

If by "name" you mean `id`, then within your function, you can access that as `_Object.id`. Because you're passing `this` in your `onload=...` (but see below), that's a reference to the element on which the event occurred. Within the function, you're receiving that argument as `_Object`, so you can use the properties on `_Object` to access information about the element, including its `id`.

---

But note that `div` elements don't have a `load` event. Also, `div` elements don't have a `parent` property; you may be thinking of `parentNode`.

Comment: OK, so if I am understanding your answer for the `parentNode` problem, would I use `_Object.id.parentNode` ?

Comment: @JohnSchultz: No, `_Object.id` is a string. In your example, if `div` elements had a `load` event, it would be `jqxParentServiceDropdownGrid`.

Comment: OK, then how do you get the "parent" set of divs?

Comment: @JohnSchultz: As I said above, it's `parentNode`: `_Object.parentNode` is the parent of `_Object`.

Comment: ok, I get that much, however to get the parent of the parent is it `(_Object.parent).parent` ?

Comment: @JohnSchultz: **Again**, it's not `parent`, it's ***`parentNode`***. Yes, since the parent of `_Object` is an element, naturally it also has the things elements have, so `_Object`'s grandparent is `_Object.parentNode.parentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, so here are a bunch of examples about returning values embedded in the HTML from a function;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".lw").click(function() {
    alert("Class:" + $(this).attr("class") + 
          "\nID:" + $(this).attr("id") + 
          "\nData:" + $(this).data("test") + 
          "\nName:" + $(this).attr("name") + 
          "\nTagname:" + $(this).prop("tagName"));
    alert($(this).parent().prop("tagName"));
  });
});
```

http://liveweave.com/CZSYqW

Clicking on either of the `<p>` elements returns a different value in an alert box.

Comment: What I am attempting to do, is create a function (or a set of functions) that can replicate the jqxgrid without retyping the same code over and over. What I have is multiple grids that need to use that same code ( different code per grid of course), but I need to replicate the code so that when I open a dialogue, the code can be reused without having it in the doc multiple times.

Comment: So you want to be able to create and destroy a jqxgrid from javascript? You want to be able to do it with a call of a function. The challenge holding you back is being able to reference an elements parent element? its tagname? its id?

Comment: Not destroy. What the page does is creates a new Service Item. If this service item is a subitem of another serviceitem that does not exist then the form opens in a dialogue window. What is holding me back is the ability to replicate the code without replicating it (if that makes sense) hence the need for a function.

Comment: providing the reference for `_Object` is accurate then `$(_Object).jqxGrid()` and `$(_Object).bind()` work as intended. Correct? Then way you find a parent object in JQuery is by using the `parent()` or `closest()` selectors. If you seek further assistance provide a more complete description of the actual problem.

Comment: I get that part. The part I am stuck on is for the DIVs, how do I create a reusable framework?

Comment: You want to make new DOM elements? `html()`.

Comment: uhh... no. I do not want to rewrite the html or add html.

Comment: Why are you hung up on the `<div>` elements?

Comment: ...You aren't calling the function. Regardless, your code may not be working, in LiveWeave, because you haven't included the resources/dependencies. In addition, there appears to be some errors using @.

Comment: It will not work in livewire because the libraries for the grid are not accessible by CDN